# Xamarin OpenEars Native Binding Not working on Device but works on Simulator

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, openears

I have been working on using OpenEars v2.03 iOS framework project in xamarin iOS Binding project. Let me explain what i did so far,.I'm new to XCode, Xamarin and all this Binding things. This gonna be a big questions, so hold your breath…

1) Build the OpenEars framework project in Xcode for Simulator.
Copied the “OpenEars” file from **Framework/OpenEars.framework/Versions/Current/** and renamed to “**libOpenEars-i386.a**”

Likewise build the same library for iPhone 4s Device by connecting the device to Mac and chosen the target to my iPhone. Finally copied the generated OpenEars and renamed it to “**libOpenEars-armv7.a**”

2) Using **lipo** command bundled the two file (libOpenEars-i386.a, libOpenEars-armv7.a) to a single file “libOpenEars.a” using the below command.

```
lipo -create -output libOpenEars.a libOpenEars-i386.a libOpenEars-armv7.a
```

3) Created a Binding project in Xamarin Studio and added the libOpenEars.a, it generates a **libOpenEars.linkwith.cs** automatically. Below is the following code,

```
using System;
using ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libOpenEars.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks="AudioToolbox AVFoundation", IsCxx=true, LinkerFlags = "-lstdc++")]
```

I tried changing the liker flags LinkerFlags = "-lstdc++ -lc++ -ObjC” and SmartLink=false.

4) My ApiDefinition file contain all interface for OpenEars, i just added only one interface here.

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Protocol]
interface OEEventsObserver
{
    [Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
    OEEventsObserverDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign), NullAllowed]
    NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

5) Referenced the OpenEars.dll to my iOS sample project.

6) Add the language model and acoustic model in the Binding library itself. (Even though it is not needed for dynamic Language model generation , i used the old OpenEars sample project from this [OpenEars Xamarin git](https://github.com/oganix/MonoTouch-OpenEars), i dind’t used the new DynamicLanguageModel generator but modified the example for latest changes).

**View Controller:**

```
public partial class OpenEarsNewApiViewController : UIViewController
{
    OEEventsObserver observer;
    OEFliteController fliteController;
    OEPocketsphinxController pocketSphinxController;


    String pathToLanguageModel;
    String pathToDictionary;
    String pathToAcousticModel;

    String firstVoiceToUse;
    String secondVoiceToUse;

    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            observer = new OEEventsObserver();
            observer.Delegate = new OpenEarsEventsObserverDelegate (this);
            pocketSphinxController = new OEPocketsphinxController ();

            fliteController = new OEFliteController();

            firstVoiceToUse = "cmu_us_slt";
            secondVoiceToUse = "cmu_us_rms";

            pathToLanguageModel = NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "OpenEars1.languagemodel";
            pathToDictionary = NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "OpenEars1.dic";
            pathToAcousticModel = NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Exception Message :"+e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine ("Inner Exception Mesage :"+e.InnerException.Message);
        }

    }

    public OpenEarsNewApiViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        init ();
    }

    #region Update

    public void UpdateStatus (String text)
    {
        txtStatus.Text = text;
    }

    public void UpdateText (String text)
    {
        txtOutput.Text = text;
    }

    public void UpdateButtonStates (bool hidden1, bool hidden2, bool hidden3, bool hidden4)
    {
        btnStartListening.Hidden = hidden1;
        btnStopListening.Hidden = hidden2;
        btnSuspend.Hidden = hidden3;
        btnResume.Hidden = hidden4;
    }

    public void Say (String text)
    {
        //fliteController.SaywithVoice (text, secondVoiceToUse);
    }

    public void StartListening ()
    {
        //pocketSphinxController.RequestMicPermission ();
        if (!pocketSphinxController.IsListening) {

            //NSString *correctPathToMyLanguageModelFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TheNameIChoseForMyLanguageModelAndDictionaryFile.%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],@"DMP"];


            pocketSphinxController.StartListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath (
                pathToLanguageModel,
                pathToDictionary,
                pathToAcousticModel,
                false
            );
        } else {
            new UIAlertView ("Notify !!","Already Listening",null,"OK","Stop").Show();

        }

    }

    public void StopListening ()
    {
        //pocketSphinxController.StopListening ();
    }

    public void SuspendRecognition ()
    {
        pocketSphinxController.SuspendRecognition ();
    }

    public void ResumeRecognition ()
    {
        pocketSphinxController.ResumeRecognition ();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    partial void btnStartListening_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        try
        {
            StartListening();
            //fliteController.Init();
            //Console.WriteLine("Speech in Progress :"+fliteController.SpeechInProgress);
            //fliteController.Say("Hai", new OEFliteVoice());

            UpdateButtonStates (true, false, false, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Speech in Progress :"+fliteController.SpeechInProgress);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    partial void btnStopListening_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        StopListening ();
        UpdateButtonStates (false, true, true, true);
    }

    partial void btnSuspend_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        SuspendRecognition ();
        UpdateButtonStates (true, false, true, false);
    }

    partial void btnResume_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        ResumeRecognition ();
        UpdateButtonStates (true, false, false, true);
    }
}
```

**OpenEarsEventsObserverDelegate:**

```
// nothing much here just to check the status and debugging 

public class OpenEarsEventsObserverDelegate:OEEventsObserverDelegate
{
    OpenEarsNewApiViewController _controller;

    public OpenEarsNewApiViewController controller {
        get {
            return _controller;
        }
        set {
            _controller = value;
        }
    }

    public OpenEarsEventsObserverDelegate (OpenEarsNewApiViewController ctrl)
    {
        controller = ctrl;
    }

    public override void PocketsphinxRecognitionLoopDidStart()
    {
        //base.PocketsphinxRecognitionLoopDidStart();

        Console.WriteLine ("Pocketsphinx is starting up");
        controller.UpdateStatus ("Pocketsphinx is starting up");
    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidReceiveHypothesis (Foundation.NSString hypothesis, Foundation.NSString recognitionScore, Foundation.NSString utteranceID)
    {
        controller.UpdateText ("Heard: " + hypothesis);
        controller.Say ("You said: " + hypothesis);
    }

    public override void PocketSphinxContinuousSetupDidFail ()
    {

    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidCompleteCalibration ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Pocket calibration is complete");
        controller.UpdateStatus ("Pocket calibratio is complete");
    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidDetectSpeech ()
    {

    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidStartListening ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Pocketsphinx is now listening");
        controller.UpdateStatus ("Pocketphinx is now listening");
        controller.UpdateButtonStates (true, false, false, true);
    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidStopListening ()
    {

    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidStartCalibration ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Pocketsphinx calibration has started.");
        controller.UpdateStatus ("Pocketsphinx calibration has started");
    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidResumeRecognition ()
    {

    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidSuspendRecognition ()
    {

    }

    public override void PocketsphinxDidDetectFinishedSpeech ()
    {

    }

    public override void FliteDidStartSpeaking ()
    {

    }

    public override void FliteDidFinishSpeaking ()
    {

    }
}
```

This works perfectly on iOS simulator but not running on real device.

[image: Simulator screen shot.]

I got this Error message while running on device.I'm getting the same message for all the interfaces.

```
Exception Message :Wrapper type 'OpenEars.OEEventsObserver' is missing its native ObjectiveC class 'OEEventsObserver'.

2015-05-15 12:55:26.996 OpenEarsNewApi[1359:231264] Unhandled managed  exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:543
```

Am i missing anything related to Binding for devices?

i tried building the same .dll using make files also, but got the same error message.

**For building OpenEars Framework:**

```
xcodebuild -project OpenEars.xcodeproj -target OpenEars -sdk iphonesimulator8.2 -arch i386 -configuration Release clean build

xcodebuild -project OpenEars.xcodeproj -target OpenEars -sdk iphoneos -arch armv7 -configuration Release clean build
```

**MAKE file for Genrating OpenEars.dll**

```
BTOUCH=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch-native

all: OpenEars.dll


OpenEars.dll: AssemblyInfo.cs OpenEars.cs libOpenEars.a
$(BTOUCH) -unsafe --new-style -out:$@ OpenEars.cs -x=AssemblyInfo.cs --link-with=libOpenEars.a,libOpenEars.a

clean:
   -rm -f *.dll
```

Check the complete mtouch [error log here](https://paste.ee/p/CvPCe)

```
$lipo -info libOpenEars.a

Architectures in the fat file: libOpenEars.a are: i386 armv7
```

Check the
    $nm -arch armv7 libOpenEars.a

[**nm command output here**](http://paste.ee/p/48eQu)

**checked the OEEvent exist in simulator (i386)**

```
$ nm -arch i386 libOpenEars.a | grep OEEvent
```

**OUTPUT**

```
U _OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
00006aa0 S l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
000076f0 S l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: no name list
libOpenEars.a(OEEventsObserver.o):
00002174 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
00002170 S _OBJC_IVAR_$_OEEventsObserver._delegate
00002188 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
00002d90 S l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
000035a0 S l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
```

**checked the OEEvent exist in armv7**

```
$nm -arch armv7 libOpenEars.a | grep OEEvent
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
00005680 S l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
000062d8 S l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
warning:    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: no name list
libOpenEars.a(OEEventsObserver.o):
00001cb4 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
00001cb0 S _OBJC_IVAR_$_OEEventsObserver._delegate
00001cc8 S _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
     U _OBJC_CLASS_$_OEEventsObserver
00002638 S l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
00002e50 S l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_OEEventsObserverDelegate
```

I'm not sure what i am missing. Yup there is lot of grammar mistakes and i Thank you for your time spend on reading this.

Comment: On what device are you building ? if you only have an `armv7` slice and are trying a **fat** application on a 64bits device then it will fail (for lack of a `arm64` slice).

Comment: @Halle i have doubt what does this means **IME supporting across platforms never works out**, and how to build a cocoa static library project (output as *.a file)as you mentioned in comment **build your own compiled framework using "Archive"** ? is it possible to build it without using lipo ? At the beginning itself i tried with no success in converting Framework project to static library, got errors for missing lot of header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @poupou and @Halle for your valuable comments. Finally i build the fat binary using all the architectures including arm64 and x86_64 (must). Used lipo to build all in one package.Now that works like charm !... Also set the project properties-> Advanced-> SupportedArchi. -> ARMv7 for running in device like ipad 2 and iPhone 4. Still need to test in iPhone 6 and 6+, i hope that might also support since they are arm64 family. I'm not sure about how this works on ARMv7s like(iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPad 4). I'm not seeing the ARMv7s support in OpenEars v2.03.