# Open Ears with Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, voice-recognition, openears

I'm trying to make a Xamarin.Forms Project with speech recognition. For Android done and easy but i'm in the hell with iOS.

I found and i readed about Open Ears.

When tried to use this, i found some problems:
 First i try to use this git: https://github.com/oganix/MonoTouch-OpenEars 
 but monotouch is not valid for Xamarin.iOS:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/41rc7iyskbwby9n/error_phoenix.png?dl=0

Next, i found this question [Xamarin OpenEars Native Binding Not working on Device but works on Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261810/xamarin-openears-native-binding-not-working-on-device-but-works-on-simulator/36127979#36127979).

After read, i tried to make a binding proyect and now i have this issue when use sharpie for autogenerate the Open Ears API:

```
/Users/cristian.fernandez/Workspace/Speech-iOS/OpenEarsDistribution/Framework/OpenEars.framework/Versions/A/Headers/acmod.h:50:10: fatal error: 'sphinxbase/cmd_ln.h' file not found
#include <sphinxbase/cmd_ln.h>
         ^

Binding...
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: annotation
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.AbstractAnnotatable.AddAnnotation (System.Object annotation) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode.AddAnnotation (System.Object annotation) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AnonymousStructMassager.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration.AcceptVisitor (IAstVisitor visitor) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitChildren (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode node) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AnonymousStructMassager.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration.AcceptVisitor (IAstVisitor visitor) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitChildren (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode node) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitSyntaxTree (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.SyntaxTree syntaxTree) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.Bind.DocumentSyntaxTree.AcceptVisitor (IAstVisitor visitor) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.Bind.BindingMassager.Massage (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode astNode, BindingTarget bindingTarget) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.Bind.BindingFrontend.Bind (Clang.Ast.Decl decl) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.BindTool.HandleTranslationUnit (Clang.Ast.TranslationUnitDecl decl) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Clang.Driver.HandleTranslationUnit (Clang.Ast.TranslationUnitDecl translationUnit) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Clang.Driver.HandleTranslationUnit (IntPtr translationUnit) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Clang.Driver:RunInternal (Clang.Driver,string[],string,Clang.Frontend.DiagnosticConsumer)
   at Clang.Driver.Run (System.String[] inputFiles, System.String[] clangArgs, Clang.Frontend.DiagnosticConsumer diagnosticConsumer) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.ParseTool.Run () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.BindTool.CoreRun () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Sharpie.BindTool.Run () in <filename unknown>:line 0
```

I use this for launch sharpie:

```
sharpie bind --output=libOpenEars --namespace=libOpenEars --sdk=iphoneos9.2 /Users/cristian.fernandez/Workspace/Speech-iOS/OpenEarsDistribution/Framework/OpenEars.framework/Versions/A/Headers/*.h
```

What can i do now besides cry?

Thanks for all and sorry for my English.

Comment: `What can i do now besides cry?` is it the only question, or you had something more specific you need help with? it's unclear what you are asking. Please, read: section [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Farside he did say "now i have this issue when use sharpie for autogenerate the Open Ears API" so it sounds like he is trying to get speech recognition working on iOS and is attempting to do it using objective sharpie but is getting errors.

Comment: @hvaughan3, I can read, but I just underlined that the question is a bit ambiguous, there are rules and recommendations, how to make the question explicit and laconic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are multiple nuget packages available for Xamarin/iOS for speech recognition, did you tried any of them?